# Delphi Seattle 10 popular um listview com imagem vinda de url - Mobile

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema mobile (Android e IOS) com Delphi Seattle 10 e me deparei com o seguinte problema:

Preciso popular um listview e para isso, recebo os dados via Json através de um servidor Rest em Php.

Estou usando os componentes abaixo para receber os dados no Delphi:

- RESTCliente
- RESTRequest
- RESTResponse
- RESTResponseDataSerAdapter1
- FDMenTable

Já recebo as informações corretamente e exibo no Listview, exceto pelo campo **imagem** por que armazeno somente o caminho dela no meu banco de dados e aí na hora de realizar o Bind no Delphi recebo o seguinte erro:

**EvalError in LinkFillControltoField1: Unable to cast or find converters between types string and Tbitmap.**

Por isso eu pergunto:
Como faço para carregar uma imagem através de sua url no listview mobile usando algo do tipo `"loadfromfile"`?

obrigado!

Diego

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve receber este erro mesmo, o Bind quer relacionar uma imagem e você esta entregando o caminho dela.

O correto é você salvar a Imagem em si no banco de dados, sugiro um `base64` e utilizar um LoadFromStream ou um Assign, de toda forma, o correto é baixar a imagem e armazena-la, para converter utilize:

```
var
  vSaida   : TStringStream;
  vEntrada : TBytesStream;
begin
  vEntrada := TBytesStream.Create;
  try
    aImagem.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(vEntrada);
    vEntrada.Position := 0;
    vSaida := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.ASCII);
    try
      TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(vEntrada, vSaida);
      Result := vSaida.DataString;
    finally
      vSaida.Free;
    end;
  finally
    vEntrada.Free;
  end;
```

Este procedimento recebe um TImage e converte em Base64, você pode modifica-lo para receber o tipo da imagem que desejar...

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda e resposta! abraços!